# How to set/call a Android Method in Unity using C#

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set parameters for a Wifi Configuration, and one of the params is to is not working, and I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Here is the Android version of what I'm trying to set using C# in Unity.

```java
WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
```

Here is what I wrote in C# that is Erroring.

```cs
using (var activity = GetActivity())
using (var wifiManager = GetWiFiManager(activity))
{
     Debug.Log("USING WIFI CONFIG");
     using (var wifiConfig = new AndroidJavaObject("android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration"))
     {
          wifiConfig.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("allowedAuthAlgorithms").Set("set", 0);
     }
}
```

So my question is how do I access the `set` method of `allowedAuthAlgorithms`? And preferably set `WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN` rather than the int value `0` in its place.

Answer (score 0):

call "set" method of allowedAuthAlgorithms

```
 wifiConfig.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("allowedAuthAlgorithms").Call<AndroidJavaObject>(("set", 0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work: It gives a `Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

     01-24 12:45:44.915: E/Unity(9693): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='allowedAuthAlgorithms' signature='()Ljava/lang/Object;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;

Comment: use  Get for  allowedAuthAlgorithms

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
using (var allowedKey = new AndroidJavaObject("java.util.BitSet"))
 {
     allowedKey.Call("set", 0);
     wifiConfig.Set("allowedAuthAlgorithms", allowedKey);
 }
```